# How to calculate totals of wpf datagrid column with dataset

Tags: c#, wpf, dataset, wpfdatagrid, calculated-columns

I am trying to figure out what is the best way to calculate a total value of DataGrid column in wpf.

- I´m using dataset to display data from sql in my DataGrid( and tableApapter for update)
- I want the info to update dynamically when I edit numbers in the DataGrid
- I want the total sum to display in label/textbox or footer below the DataGrid

What is the best practice to do this ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can listen on various events that will cause a value in the column to change, and then compute the total whenever the event is fired by calling a method like "calculateTotal()" below.

DataTables events are defined here: [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w9y9a401.aspx)

```
private int colTotal = 0; // class level

public Myclass()
{ 
    // Add a ColumnChanged event handler for the table.
    MyDataTable.ColumnChanged += new DataColumnChangeEventHandler(Column_Changed);
    // wire up more event handlers here..
}

private static void Column_Changed(object sender, DataColumnChangeEventArgs e )
{
   calculateTotal();
}

// calculate total of specified column
void calculateTotal()
{
   colTotal = myDataSet.Tables["myTable"].Compute("SUM(myColumnName)", String.Empty);
}
```

colTotal will be a public property that is bound to your textbox or label

```
public int ColTotal
{
    get 
    { 
      return colTotal; 
    }
    set
    {
      colTotal= value;
      OnPropertyChanged("ColTotal");
    }
}
```

Comment: two additional questions; what is dsPoint and how do you bind textbox to the public property ?

Comment: I figured it out. Thanks a lot !

Comment: One extra question. How would I perform this line if I wanted to add Where clause to it ?
    colTotal = myDataSet.Tables["myTable"].Compute("SUM(myColumnName)", String.Empty)

Comment: What's the WHERE clause supposed to filter out?

Comment: I want to calculate certain parts of my table only where a boolean property column is set to 0

Answer (score 0):

You have to use either for loop or while inside your DataSet Table Row or DataGrid, Sum it and display the result in a Label

or

You can use `Compute` on DataSet Table Column